# Manage Contact Groups on Droid X

Tags: contacts, 2.1-eclair

On the Droid X I'm able to create contact groups. However I don't seem to be able to add/delete group members. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Well I just did the OTA update so I'm not sure if it was there before, but now when viewing a group I can see the Edit Group button when displaying a group in the contacts.